# Draw contour returns heap error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am using OpenCv 2.49 and VS2010 professional

When I use almost same code from the OpenCV examples, the findcontours function gives a heap corruption.

```
findContours(Mask, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
    drawContours( *pImg, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
}
```

And check the input image type, which is not 8UC1 and not empty
I guess it is because the environment setting.

But I cannot figure out how the error comes from

In Solution->Properties
Additional include directories is

> C:\opencv249\opencv\build\include

Runtime library is

> Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

In Linker tab, the additional library directories is

> C:\opencv249\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib

input dependencies are

```
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
Kinect10.lib
opencv_gpu249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_nonfree249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_ocl249d.lib
opencv_photo249d.lib
opencv_stitching249d.lib
opencv_superres249d.lib
opencv_ts249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_videostab249d.lib
comctl32.lib
```

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Where is your `hierarchy` in the `drawContours()` coming from?